# Microsoft SQL Server generates two select queries and puts data in separate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for a query that separate the data with the condition `WHERE` in the same output but in separates columns.

Example: I have the table `Product_2`:

[image]

I have two separates queries (to separate the products by Produt_Tag):

```
SELECT 
    Product_Mark AS "PIT-10_Product_Mark", 
    Product_Model AS "PIT-10_Product_Model"
FROM Product_2
WHERE Product_Tag = 'PIT-10';

SELECT 
    Product_Mark AS "PIT-11_Product_Mark", 
    Product_Model AS "PIT-11_Product_Model"
FROM Product_2
WHERE Product_Tag = 'PIT-11';
```

And I get this output:

[image]

But I need the output to be like this:

[image]

Can someone tell me how I need to modify my query to have the four columns in the same table/ output?

Thank you

I forgot to tell that in the data I Have the “Porduct_Mark” that only appears one time. (in reality the data in “Product_Mark” is the name of the place where the instrument is located and one place can have one or two instruments “Product_Model”. At the end I’m looking for the result show in the image here below. I tried to use LEFT JOIN but that don’t work.

here is the new table "Product_2"
[image]

Result that I'm looking for:
[image]

Luis Ardila

Comment: You can join the two tables on PIT-10_Product_Mark and PIT-11_Product_Mark if you really need that output. However its probably better to combine it to one query with product_tag in ('PIT-10', 'PIT-11')

Comment: I assume in your sample table that PIT-10 Product Mark and PIT-11 Product mark will always have identical values in the same row. Can there ever be a "C" for just one product Tag?

Comment: Hi Nick. Yes there are elements with only a product tag. I upgraded my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming Product_PK is the primary key for the table and the repeated value 1002 shown in the question is a mistake. Considering this assumption, you can get the result set using self join as below.

```
SELECT pa.Product_Mark AS "PIT-10_Product_Mark", pa.Product_Model AS "PIT-10_Product_Model",
       pb.Product_Mark AS "PIT-11_Product_Mark", pb.Product_Model AS "PIT-11_Product_Model" 
FROM Product_2 pa 
  INNER JOIN Product_2 pb 
  ON pa.Product_Mark = pb.Product_Mark
WHERE pa.product_pk != pb.product_pk
and pa.Product_Tag = 'PIT-10'
and pb.Product_Tag = 'PIT-11';
```

verified same in https://dbfiddle.uk/NiOO8zc1

Comment: Hi Sankar. Thanks for the solution. That really works but I forgot to tell that in the data I Have the “Porduct_Mark” that only appears one time. (in reality, the data in “Product_Mark” is the name of the place where the instrument is located and one place can have one or two instruments “Product_Model”. At the end, I’m looking for the result shown in the image added. I tried to use LEFT JOIN but that doesn’t work.